# Add values in loop in the end of URL inl Python from list and append output

Tags: python, loops

I'm trying to get values from URL with Rest API.
I need to run a loop using values from file, query the website and append the results to one file.

The file serial_no_list contains serial #'s:

111, 222, 333, 444..

I need to add each of the serials to the end of the URL:

```
/v1/clusterview/get-cluster-summary/111
/v1/clusterview/get-cluster-summary/222
...
/v1/clusterview/get-cluster-summary/999999
```

And append the result of the output to one file

P.S
I tried to use:

```
"/v1/clusterview/get-cluster-summary/"+contents
```

Doesn't work

### Please assist

```
with open('serial_no_list') as f:
    contents = f.read()

conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection("api.activeiq.netapp.com")
conn.request("GET", "/v1/clusterview/get-cluster-summary/{}", headers=headers)

res = conn.getresponse()
data = res.read()
print(data.decode("utf-8"))
```

Comment: `for i in contents: url = '.../' + i`…? Something along those lines…?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `111, 222, 333, 444` mean the numbers are in one line, you can split the list by commas and use string formatting.

```
total=[]
with open('serial_no_list') as f:
    contents = f.read()
    for i in contents.strip("\n").split(","):
        conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection("api.activeiq.netapp.com")
        conn.request("GET", f"/v1/clusterview/get-cluster-summary/{i}", 
        headers=headers)

        data = res.read()
        new_d=data.decode("utf-8")

        total.append(new_d)
....
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this.

Assuming the contents of `serial_no_list.txt` are like this:

```
111
222
333
444
```

This code will concatenate the serial numbers with the URL.

```py
url = '/v1/clusterview/get-cluster-summary/'

with open('serial_no_list.txt') as f:
    for i in f.readlines():
        new_url = url + i.strip()
        print(new_url)
```

```
/v1/clusterview/get-cluster-summary/111
/v1/clusterview/get-cluster-summary/222
/v1/clusterview/get-cluster-summary/333
/v1/clusterview/get-cluster-summary/444
```